# Error while removing python in pop os 22.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-22.04

encountered an error while trying to remove python3

os: pop os 22.04

python version: 3.10

command:

`sudo apt remove python3`

output:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  pop-default-settings
> : Depends: gnome-menus but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: plymouth-theme-pop-basic but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: python3-repolib (> 1.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: ubuntu-minimal but it is not going to be installed  pop-desktop : Depends: pop-session but it is not going
> to be installed
>                Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: language-selector-gnome but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: chrome-gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: gnome-orca but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: gnome-menus but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: gvfs-backends
>                Depends: ibus-table but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: pop-upgrade but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: mesa-vulkan-drivers but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: openprinting-ppds but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: ubuntu-drivers-common but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: gedit but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: ibus-table-emoji but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: pop-shop but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: pop-transition but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: yelp but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: gnome-shell-extension-prefs but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: sessioninstaller but it is not going to be installed
>                Recommends: hidpi-daemon but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this
> may be caused by held packages.
```

Trying to uninstall python 3.10 to install the latest version of python

I tried installing python 3.11 along with 3.10 but had problems with not being able to install modules using pip in virtual environments.

Pop os does not need python to run as far as i know so this error should not have occurred

Comment: Never ever uninstall the system Python version. Instead you can install multiple Python versions in parallel.

Comment: i tried using a different python version along with this one but it had problems when i tried installing modules using pip

Comment: some ssl error occurred but openssl was installed and i tried all the ways to make it work